# Twitter4j getting full text Tweets

Tags: twitter4j

I'm trying to get the full text of tweets, recent answers say to use

```
twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder()
.setOAuthConsumerKey("")) 
.setOAuthConsumerSecret("") 
.setOAuthAccessToken("")
.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("")
.setTweetModeExtended(true)
```

but it seems like the latest version of twitter4j api removed the .setTweetModeExtended method.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Twitter4j version 4.0 and the trick which is working for me is -

```
if (status.getRetweetedStatus() != null) {
                System.out.println(status.getRetweetedStatus().getText());
            } else if (status.getRetweetedStatus() == null) {
                System.out.println(status.getText());
            }
```

`.setTweetModeExtended(true)` to the configuration builder is also required as you have already used.